# Is "Doing exercise can stay healthy" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I think it should be: Doing exercise can help people stay healthy, because "Doing exercise" the action cannot be the agent of the verb "stay".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a definition of "grammatical" that assumes that nonsense is necessarily ungrammatical, then it's ungrammatical. But for most grammarians, it is grammatical. Semantically it's incoherent, for the reasons you give. and your emendation is much better.

Having said that, many of us say things that, when analysed, are just as nonsensical. I don't think many native English speakers would say your sentence, but I think it would be readily understood.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right that "Doing exercise can help people stay healthy" is the correct way of expressing this idea, since "doing exercise" is not the thing that is staying.

As @Colin Fine notes, this isn't an issue of whether the sentence is syntactically correct; it's an issue of whether the sentence makes sense semantically.

Comment: Another possible interpretation is "[by] doing excercise, [you] can stay healthy".

Comment: This still sounds weird to me. Usually the only time you use "do" in this way is when you're saying "doing exercises" (plural), as in when you "do exercises" as part of physical therapy to rehabilitate after an injury, rather than as part of a general fitness program to stay healthy. Otherwise, you'd typically just say "Exercising can help people stay healthy."